# netty does not detect netty-tcnative

Tags: netty, grpc-java

While looking deeper into my issue, explained atg [gRpc with TLS Client Authentication using SunPKCS11 in netty fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44161427/grpc-with-tls-client-authentication-using-sunpkcs11-in-netty-fails), I changed the version of netty-tcnative-boringssl. The cange in my build.gradle was from

```
compile 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:1.1.33.Fork26'
```

to

```
compile 'io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:+'
```

resulting in:

> +--- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:+ -> 2.0.1.Final

I did this, because according to netty's javadoc `SslContextBuilder's` `keyManager(KeyManagerFactory factory)` method also works for OpenSSL as provider, which it does not for version 1.1.33.Fork26.

Now, with the new version the slf4j debug output of netty tells me:

> [main] DEBUG io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl - netty-tcnative not in the
>   classpath; OpenSslEngine will be unavailable

So the detection of netty-tcnative seems to fail. Debugging into 
 `io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSsl`'s static code block,
the detection fails, because

```
Class.forName("org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSL", false, OpenSsl.class.getClassLoader());
```

throws an exception.
Do I do something wrong, or is this some resurgence of 
lat years issues (https://github.com/relayrides/pushy/issues/303 and https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/136)? 
// working on 64 bit Win 10 with Oracle Java 1.8.21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grpc Java 1.3.0 did not support netty version 2.*. Waiting and updating to gRPC java 1.4.0 did the trick out of the box, as support for netty 2.* was included with commit https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/commit/67eefa69b4009948ac664691e719f683c4478290.